# requirejs and bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

I have a problem when I try to set the format with date time picker. The debugger tells me that

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
```

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Web Project</title>

    <link href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script data-main="Scripts/app.js" src="Scripts/Libs/require.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The main html sets up and loads requirejs which itself is loading my app.js. In there I'll try to set the date picker format when the document is ready. Please see below.

```
requirejs.config({

    // by default load any module IDs from Scripts/libs
    baseUrl: 'Scripts/Libs',

    paths: {
        models: '../models',
        collections: '../collections',
        views: '../views',
        routers: '../routers',
        components: '../components',
        modelDialog: 'backbone.ModalDialog',
        bootstrap: 'bootstrap.min',
        boostrapDatePicker: 'bootstrap-datetimepicker.min',
    },

    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'boostrapDatePicker': {
            deps: ['moment', 'jquery', 'bootstrap']
        }

    }

});

var app = app || {};

require(['components/dataService'], function(dataService) {

    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ format:'MM/DD/YYYY'});

        dataService.getData();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add 'jquery' and 'boostrapDatePicker' to your require array:

```
require(['components/dataService', 'jquery', 'boostrapDatePicker'], function(dataService, $) {
  ...
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the issue may be that you are getting

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

returned because datetimepicker is possibly not getting imported/loaded correctly or you could possibly be missing a dependancy.

Comment: This answer is redundant, seeing as [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32983774/1906307), which was posted months before yours, *already* demonstrated what you hypothesize in your answer.